# Kendo - form, message box

Tags: forms, messagebox

I am evaluating different JavaScript frameworks.
Does Kendo UI includes 'helpers' that simplify creating forms and message windows?

Thanks, alon

Answer (score 0):

Kendo web is a suite of component that operate in the client. Speak about form has no sense, because the kendo components works with json ajax request with the server services. The suite can works over WEB pure html component, also integrate with MVC 4. Exist a community edition that you can download from Telerik(r) web site if you want to test it.

The suite has a Window widget. You can construct from it your message box, but does not have message box individual component. Exists a third party extension with many of these boxes. (Kendo UI Extension).
I hope that this help you